# Make a prompt look good while still letting JavaScript pause

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, implementation

So I want to make a custom prompt/alert/confirm box, but I have it so that many of those happen in sequence. In a normal prompt, this wouldn't be an issue because the JavaScript pauses and waits for the user to click "OK" or "Cancel" Before continuing execution, however a custom box I fear could break the whole system. I've seen some Things about async and stuff, but they're kind of confusing.

If you wanna see the code github is https://github.com/NonzeroCornet/universalai

I'd leave it how it is, but I want to submit it to Experiments with Google and it needs to look good.

Comment: Maybe using something like https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/ would be a good start. You'll definitely need to make use of asynchronous programming techniques to do something like what you want.

Comment: @CollinD does sweetalert wait for a prompt to finish before continuing execution?

Comment: @NonzeroCornet34 No, it doesn't. There's no way you could make JS to pause, only some native DOM methods can do that. You've to take the bull by the horns and learn how to program [asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).

Answer (score 2):

There have been some news in this matter if you'd like to go more native way, depending on your browser compatibility you could use [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) along with [inert attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) and style the dialog & backdrop to your needs.